# UICollectionViewCell AutoLayout issue in Xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I have created a uicollectionview cell in interface builder file,also I have set all the necessary constraints for that cell,It’s working fine,But when we quit /close the Xcode and reopen the cell ,it will be automatically reduce the size and constraints are conflicted,How can I solve this issue?
[image]